# Adobe Animate CC HTML5 canvas conflicting ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame

Tags: html, flash, adobe

I am very stymied and frustrated by this problem. I am trying to create an interactive slideshow that jumps around based on user input. I am using Adobe Animate CC on an HTML5 canvas.

On the first slide I have this code:

```
this.stop();

this.Slide01_01But.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    this.gotoAndPlay("Slide02");
}

this.Slide01_01But.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3()
{
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    this.gotoAndPlay("Slide03");
}
```

The first button works fine.  The second button, however, only turns off the audio and doesn't go to where I asked it to.  I tried adding a remove event listener function has suggested in an older query, but that didn't work and broke even more stuff.  Can you not have more than one ClickToGoToAndPlay in one frame?

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: I though it might be because I have the stop sound code in there so I changed it to a standard click event.  Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had some instances wrong later in the presentation that somehow threw everything off.  Not sure why that affected the first button, but...seems fixed now

Answer (score -1):

if you make the second button copy from first ,

make duplicate simple for second and if the problem still work ,after `createjs.Sound.stop();`

do code called the sound again